# Get indirect relationship from collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have:

```
User->hasMany('Order')
```

...

```
Order->hasMany('Product')
```

...

```
$users=User::with('orders','orders.product')->...
```

how can I retrieve all products bought from users in $users taking advantage of eager loading instead of doing other queries?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hasManyThrough relationship on your User model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\Order');
}
```

or, using a collection, as your already eager loading.

```
$products = User::with('orders','orders.product')->flatMap(function(User $user) {
    return $user->orders->flatMap(function(Order $order) {
        return $order->products;
    });
});
```